# Performance Tuning While Loading CSV

Tags: java, performance, oracle

I have attached below code

**Functionality**

Reading csv and insert in db after replacing values with webmacro.

Reading values from csv @ first header information **NO,NAME** next to that read one by one values and put into webmacro context context.put("1","RAJARAJAN") next webmacro replace $(NO) ==>1 and $(NAME)==>RAJARAJAN and add in statment batch once it reached 1000 execute the batch.

Code is running as per functionality but it takes 4 minutes to parse 50,000 records need performance improvement or need to change logic ....kindly let me know if any doubts.
Any change to drastic performance...

**Note:** I use webmacro because to replace $(NO) in merge query to values read in CSV

**Bala.csv**

```
    NO?NAME
    1?RAJARAJAN
    2?ARUN
    3?ARUNKUMAR

Connection con=null;
Statement stmt=null;
Connection con1=null;
int counter=0;
    try{
         WebMacro wm = new WM();
         Context context = wm.getContext();
         String strFilePath = "/home/vbalamurugan/3A/email-1822820895/Bala.csv";
         String msg="merge into temp2  A using
         (select '$(NO)' NO,'$(NAME)' NAME from dual)B on(A.NO=B.NO)
                   when not matched then  insert (NO,NAME)
                      values(B.NO,B.NAME) when matched then
                      update set A.NAME='Attai' where A.NO='$(NO)'"; 
         String[]rowsAsTokens;
         con=getOracleConnection("localhost","raymedi_hq","raymedi_hq","XE");
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
         stmt=con.createStatement();
         File file = new File(strFilePath);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        try {
            String headerField;
            String header[];
            headerField=scanner.nextLine();
            header=headerField.split("\\?");
            long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {      
                String scan[]=scanner.nextLine().split("\\?");
                for(int i=0;i<scan.length;i++){
                    context.put(header[i],scan[i]);
                }
          if(context.size()>0){
                String m=replacingWebMacroStatement(msg,wm,context);
                if(counter>1000){
                    stmt.executeBatch();
                    stmt.clearBatch();
                    counter=0;
                }else{
                    stmt.addBatch(m);
                    counter++;
                }

                  }
        }
    long b=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
    System.out.println("=======Total Time Taken"+b);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      finally {
         scanner.close();
       }      
              stmt.executeBatch();
              stmt.clearBatch();
              stmt.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          con.rollback();

      }finally{
          con.commit();

      }

// Method For replace webmacro with $
 public static String replacingWebMacroStatement(String Query, WebMacro wm,Context context) throws Exception {

    Template template = new StringTemplate(wm.getBroker(), Query);
    template.parse();
    String macro_replaced = template.evaluateAsString(context);
    return macro_replaced;
}
// for getting oracle connection
 public static Connection getOracleConnection(String IPaddress,String username,String password,String Tns)throws SQLException{
      Connection connection = null;
      try{
      String baseconnectionurl ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+IPaddress+":1521:"+Tns;
      String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      String user = username;
      String pass = password;
      Class.forName(driver);
      connection=DriverManager.getConnection(baseconnectionurl,user,pass);
      }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return connection;
    }
```

Comment: Step 1: Run a performance profiler and understand where time is being spent executing your code.

Comment: Why aren't you using SQL*Loader or external tables? Both of which have been optimised for specifically this role.

Comment: I am new to java how to run performance profiler i am using eclipse

Comment: @Ben I want replace csv values with merge statement it is possible with sql *Loader

Comment: @BALASCJP - no, but you can use MERGE with an external table, because we can execute regular SQL against external tables.

Comment: see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html for java sun java profiler. Also for parsing don't use split as it creates too many new objects. Use StringTokenizer instead

Comment: @Masood_mj Change split to StringTokenizer but no big difference kindly suggest to overcome that

Comment: BALASCJP _ why ignore all the comments about Oracle external tables??!

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi I cant catch u pls can u explain it ??

Comment: creating an external table (or using sqlloader and then the a query) would be very easy to implement. Is that not an option for you?

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi what about performance to load approx 2 lakhs records.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that this code takes on average about 150ms on my machine:

```
    StrTokenizer tokenizer = StrTokenizer.getCSVInstance();
    for (int i=0;i<50000;i++) {
        tokenizer.reset("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z");
        String toks[] = tokenizer.getTokenArray();
    }
```

You'll find StrTokenizer in the apache commons-lang package, but  I would doubt that String.split(), StringTokenizer or Scanner.nextLine() would be your bottleneck in any case.  I would assume it's your database inserts times.

If that's the case you can do 1 of two things:

1. Tune your batch size.
2. Multithread the inserts

And as suggested, a profiler will help to determine where your time is spent.,